# Ruby hash["string".to_sym].nil? keeps returning true regardless of key item exist or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

I've been trying to search and figure out why when using something["string".to_sym].nil? it alway return true. for example:

```
movies = {
    the_matrix: 5, 
    sin_city: 3.5, 
    days: 1
}

puts "What would you like to do?"
puts "*** Type add to add a movie."
choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
    puts "Please input the movie title:"
    title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].nil?            #check to see if the movie title exists 
        puts "What rating would you give this movie?"
        rating = gets.chomp
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    else
        puts "The movie title is in the database!"
    end
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```

It seems like the syntax, .to_sym, only works with one-word input.

When I type "days", it gives the correct response: "The movie title is in the database!"

When I type "the matrix" after the prompt, instead of recognizing the movie is already in the hash,  it asks for the rating of the movie.

I did some testing and found out that

```
movies[title.to_sym].nil?
```

always return true regardless if the title contains more than one word. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
movies[title.gsub(' ', '_').to_sym]
```

Symbolizing a string does not convert spaces to underscores.